# Check all checkbox in respective columns

Tags: jquery, html

Without class or id, how to check all checkboxes in the same column? I have the screenshot of my table, HTML and jquery code below:

**Screenshot**

Notice that I use rowspan and colspan will it affect anything?
[image]

**HTML code**

When  I click on the Read checkbox, same column will be check. But when I click on the Create column, still it trigger the Read column's checkboxes.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_perm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Modules (Page)</th>
            <th colspan="4">Permissions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Read <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
            <th>Create <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
            <th>Edit <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
            <th>Delete <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="1">
        <td>Page 1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="r"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="c"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="e"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="d"></td>
    </tr><tr data-id="6">
        <td>Page 2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="r"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="c"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="e"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="d"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$("th p input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    var cb = $(this),          //checkbox that was changed
       th = cb.parent(),      //get parent th
       col = th.index() + 2;  //get column index. note nth-child starts at 1, not zero

    $("tbody td:nth-child(" + col + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked);  //select the inputs and [un]check it
});
```

Comment: The parent of your checkbox is a paragraph tag, not `th`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.parent()` points to `p`, not `th` so...

**Use `.closest("th")`** to get the closest `th`

```js
$("th input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    var $cb = $(this),         
        $th = $cb.closest("th"), // get parent th
        col = $th.index() + 2;  // get column index. note nth-child starts at 1, not zero
    $("tbody td:nth-child(" + col + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked);  //select the inputs and [un]check it
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_perm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Modules (Page)</th>
            <th colspan="4">Permissions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Read <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
            <th>Create <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
            <th>Edit <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
            <th>Delete <p><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="1">
        <td>Page 1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="r"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="c"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="e"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="d"></td>
    </tr><tr data-id="6">
        <td>Page 2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="r"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="c"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="e"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" value="d"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

What you're still missing is:

> if *super checkbox* is selected - but than one of the column checkboxes is deselected → the super checkbox should deselect as well.

but thumbs up!

Comment: Are you able to assist in the missing part too? I guess the logic is to check in the `tbody` if any checkbox was deselected, then it will make sure that the respective `th` checkbox deselect too. Am I right?

Comment: @LeaveCover yes. The logic is pretty similar, copy paste what you have and use the right selectors